# How can I optimize the read from S3?

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-glue, aws-glue-spark, aws-glue3.0

```
 dyf_pagewise_word_count = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(
 connection_type="s3",
 format="csv",
 connection_options={
     "paths": ["s3://somefile.csv/"],
     'recurse':True, 
     'groupFiles': 'inPartition', 
     'groupSize': '100000'
 },
 format_options={
     "withHeader": True,
     "separator": ","
 }
)
```

It takes 45 secs to read from S3. Is there any way to optimize the read time?

Answer (score 0):

You could try the `optimizePerformance`option if you're using glue 3.0.  It batches records to reduce IO.  See [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-format.html) for more details

```
dyf_pagewise_word_count = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(
 connection_type="s3",
 format="csv",
 connection_options={
     "paths": ["s3://somefile.csv/"],
     'recurse':True, 
     'groupFiles': 'inPartition', 
     'groupSize': '100000'
 },
 format_options={
     "withHeader": True,
     "separator": ",",
     "optimizePerformance": True, 
 }
)
```

Also, could you convert the CSV to something like Parquet upstream of the read?

Comment: "optimizePerformance": True. Still read is 45 secs. no improvement.